# Typescript Discriminating Union for React Reducer Dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, discriminated-union

I'm attempting to do something that I thought would be simple. I simply want to turn React's reducer function (`dispatch` below) into a function (`dispatcher()` below) that accepts the `type` and `payload` properties as 2 parameters. However the type checking doesn't work as expected.  I get the following error, which I suspect has something to do with the fact that the `type` and `payload` parameters of `dispatcher()` aren't actually connected to each other:

```
Argument of type '{ type: "select" | "precycle" | "preview"; payload: Project | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CarAction'.
  Type '{ type: "select" | "precycle" | "preview"; payload: Project | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "preview"; payload: Project | undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"select" | "precycle" | "preview"' is not assignable to type '"preview"'.
        Type '"select"' is not assignable to type '"preview"'.ts(2345)
```

Code:

```js
type CarAction =
  | {
      type: "select" | "precycle";
      payload: Project;
    }
  | {
      type: "preview";
      payload: Project | undefined;
    };

 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);
 const dispatcher = (type: CarAction["type"], payload: CarAction["payload"]) => {
      dispatch({ type, payload });
    };
```

Comment: What is `reducer` and `initState`? Can't help without it.